# How to pass data from one component to another in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have a main component where i have imported one component, so i want to pass some data from that imported component to the main component and display it. here is an example code:
this is my main file:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import TestComponent from "../components/TestComponent";
function TestScreen(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <TestComponent />
      <Text>{location}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TestScreen;
```

and this is the Imported component:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
function TestComponent(props) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Boiler</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text onPress={() => setLocation("Me")}>Click</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```

now i want to get the `location` hook from the `TestComponent` component and use it the the `TestScreen` Component, how can i do that

Comment: Coming from an MVC world, it seems like you've located your `Controller` at too low a level

Answer (score 1):

You should lift state up to parent component

```
function TestScreen(props) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  return (
    <View>
      <TestComponent setLocation={setLocation} location={location}/>
      <Text>{location}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}


function TestComponent({ location, setLocation }) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Boiler</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text onPress={() => setLocation("Me")}>Click</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And now you have access to `location` in parent

Answer (score 0):

You have declare you data and pass the data as prop to childer componen, parent data could be array, objects, states and so on:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
import TestComponent from "../components/TestComponent";
function TestScreen(props) {
const data = {name: 'im parent data'; otherProperty: 'im other property'}
  return (
    <View>
      <TestComponent />
    PASS DATA AS PROP
      <Text data={data}>{location}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TestScreen;
```

Acces to parent data with dot notation:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
function TestComponent(props) {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Boiler</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text onPress={() => setLocation("Me")}>Click</Text>
      <h1>{props.data.name}</h1>
      <h1>{props.data.otherProperty}</h1>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;
```